# what do I need to do before I send a server computer to my customer?

Tags: mysql

I write a server program to monit some device (by using udp), and this program(with the server computer) need send to my customer.

they know nothing about computer, and are far far away, and with bad network condition(maybe I cannot remote login to this computer), so I don't want anything bad happen..

what kinds of problems should I consider?

ps: some detail: I'm using ubuntu10.04 desktop version + tornado + sqlalchemy + mysql + zeromq,
I'm using monit to keep those program running..

edit:

maybe this topic is generically, I think it is important for those who face the same problem. system admin always face problem never encountered before, and learn by failure is expensive. maybe there is a book for this?

Comment: Are the remote access problems due to issues at your end or the customer's end? If you're in the business of writing, deploying and managing software then a good network connection is essential. If its at the customer end and you're supplying network monitoring softwaer - make sure you're getting paid by the hour - and charge them for expenses for you to make a site visit!

Answer (score 3):

There could be any number of things that you'll need to know before you can deploy your computer into their system.

1. Default sysadmin password
2. IP Address to be assigned, or should DHCP be used
3. Should the system startup automatically after a power failure

Odds are you'll need to go and install the machine at their site otherwise there's no way of knowing that it's fired up correctly and that the network router has been setup for you to remote into it as needed.

Comment: also you can create a how to documentation to explain step by step every bit of thing they need to know about the server.

Answer (score 2):

- Protect the system from unexpected power loss by providing a UPS and software to monitor it and shut the system down automagically before the battery is exhausted.
- Assume that the above will fail so power drops unexpectedly. Can you make your 'server' run off a live CD (or similar)?
- Provide an automated backup solution that (as frequently as necessary) dumps the dynamic data to removable media. Provide documentation for this and how to restore the data when required - test all of this.
- Document and test all processes that the users will be required to carry out on the system.

You should also list things ypu will not be responsible for e.g.

- Providing backup media
- Changing backup media

...